# Bash scripting grep variable from multilined json?

Tags: json, bash, grep

I have a JSON file that has many instances like this..:

```
{
  "SensorApp": "Open Hardware Monitor",
  "SensorClass": "Temperature",
  "SensorName": "Intel Core i7-4790: CPU Core #4",
  "SensorValue": "31",
  "SensorUnit": "C",
  "SensorUpdateTime": 0
},
{
  "SensorApp": "Open Hardware Monitor",
  "SensorClass": "Temperature",
  "SensorName": "Intel Core i7-4790: CPU Package",
  "SensorValue": "32",
  "SensorUnit": "C",
  "SensorUpdateTime": 0
},
{
  "SensorApp": "Open Hardware Monitor",
  "SensorClass": "Clock",
  "SensorName": "Intel Core i7-4790: CPU Core #1",
  "SensorValue": "3899.165",
  "SensorUnit": "MHz",
  "SensorUpdateTime": 0
},
```

And so forth. I need to assign a variable, say var1 to the sensor value in:

```
{
  "SensorApp": "Open Hardware Monitor",
  "SensorClass": "Temperature",
  "SensorName": "Intel Core i7-4790: CPU Package",
  "SensorValue": "32",
  "SensorUnit": "C",
  "SensorUpdateTime": 0
},
```

I've tried a few questions already in stackoverflow, however none of them seem to work with multi-lined JSON files.

Any ideas how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to change the value in the json file to a value of a shell variable or if you want to set a shell variable to the value of the `SensorValue` field in the json.

However, for both tasks you can use [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

- **Iterating over json values in bash**

```sh
jq -r '.[].SensorValue' file.json | while read -r value ; do
    # Do something useful with the value
    echo "$value"
done
```

- **Modifying a json file from bash**

```sh
VALUE=123
jq ".[].SensorValue = $VALUE" file.json
```

---

**Update**: In comments you told you want to extract the `SensorValue` out of that json object where `SensorName` equals `"Intel Core i7-4790: CPU Package"`. In `jq` you are using the `select()` function for that:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.SensorName == "Intel Core i7-4790: CPU Package").SensorValue' file.json
```

Output:

```
32
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, i wrote this question very late at night. I need to pull the values out of the json file. With your jq solution, how would i set it to only pull the value from a specific section? Right now it just spits back all the matching variables.

For example, i only want the value immediately following " "Intel Core i7-4790: CPU Package",".

Comment: @user2809413 What you have in mind is possible with `jq` and is one of it's key features. I have updated my answer and added an example. Note that `jq` is getting more and more a standard tool for working with json in the shell.